# Tuple2._2 used as key in map.apply

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In Scala v2.9.2 (and 2.8.0), this script:

```
case class MyString(s: String)
implicit def stringToMyString(s: String) = MyString(s)
implicit val defaults: Map[String, MyString] = Map("abc" -> MyString("123"))

case class HasDefaults(name: String = "none", 
    baseMap: Map[String, MyString] = Map.empty) {
  def add(kvp: (String, MyString)*)(implicit defaults: Map[String, MyString]) =
    this.copy(baseMap = this.baseMap ++ defaults ++ kvp)
}

val hasDefaults = HasDefaults() add (
  "def" -> "124",
  "xyz" -> MyString("999")
)

println(hasDefaults)
```

Fails with:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: 124
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.default(Map.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:135)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.apply(Map.scala:106)
    at Main$$anon$1.<init>(HasDefaults.scala:12)
```

It is trying to use the String value `"124"` as a key in a map lookup, even though it is defined as a value (by virtue of being on the right hand side of the `->` operator).

Note, this error goes away if the implicit conversion to `MyString` is not attempted. e.g.:

```
val hasDefaults = HasDefaults().add(
  "def" -> MyString("124"),
  "xyz" -> MyString("999")
)
```

Note #2, the error also goes away if the implicit parameter is provided explicitly. e.g.:

```
val hasDefaults = HasDefaults().add(
  "def" -> "124",
  "xyz" -> MyString("999")
)(Map("abc" -> MyString("123")))
```

Comment: As a collorary to missingfaktor's answer, never use standard types as implicits.

Comment: Thanks. For the reason exposed by this example, or for other reasons?

Comment: For this as well as other similar problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala, `Map` is a function. (`Map[A, B] <: PartialFunction[A, B] <: A => B`.) So `defaults` acts like an implicit conversion from `String` to `MyString`. Since `defaults` does not contain `"124"`, you get a "key not found" error.